# Django loginform not authenticating and redirecting to next url

Tags: django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-authentication, django-class-based-views

I have a multi user application where i am trying to authenticate the user if i put the wrong credentials it is not raising the form errors instead it is redirecting me to the login_url that is mentioned in settings.py file

**forms.py**

```
class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(required=True)
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request = kwargs.pop('request', None)
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def clean(self):
        username = self.cleaned_data.get("username")
        password = self.cleaned_data.get("password")
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(username=username)
            if user.user_a:
                if user.check_password(password):
                    return self.cleaned_data
                else:
                    self.add_error("password", forms.ValidationError("Password is wrong."))
        except models.User.DoesNotExist:
            self.add_error("email", forms.ValidationError("User does not exist."))
```

**views.py**

```
class LoginView(FormView):
    template_name = 'login.html'
    form_class = LoginForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy("home")
```

**settings.py**

```
LOGIN_URL = 'index'
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason why you're not using the built-in Django Auth views and forms?

Trying to roll your own auth system is notoriously difficult and error-prone. I'd highly recommend using the built-in views and forms.

You can find more information about the Django Auth system here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/